# Application stopped working

Tags: java, android, string

I am making an android app in java.. And basicaly i have a problem.. I have a button which is removing the last char in a string.. And this button will be used alot and if the user is pressing the button while the string is empty the application gets an error message and closes.. And i want to prevent this somehow..

This is current code for the onClickListener..

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
                numbersArea.setText(value);
        }
```

Any idea how i would do this?? Since im out of ideas after trying all yesterday night.

Comment: check this if(value!=null&&value!=""){value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
                numbersArea.setText(value);
}

Comment: testung for equality between strings must be done with equals, not ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your listener like this:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!value.equals("") && value != null) {
                   value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
                   numbersArea.setText(value);
                }
        }
```

Basically, what it does is verify if the string is empty and different of null, if its not, it enters in the `if` statement.

Please, let me know if you have more doubts.

Thanks.

Comment: Fantasitic help! I realy like it.. I triend this same thing before but i just wrote !value.equals("") nothing else..

Comment: TextUtils.isEmpty(value) is a cleaner way to test for emptyness. Your example crashes is value is null or if value.length == 0

Answer (score 3):

Before `substring`, make sure the length of the string is > 0.

```
if (!value.isEmpty()) {
    value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
    numbersArea.setText(value);
}
```

If you don't do this check, at some point the string will have zero length and `substring()` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.